# Python 3.6/ Django1.10 @login_required decorator redirects to link with missing "/"

Tags: python, django, python-3.6, django-1.10

I am using a decorator login_required on my project Django 1.10 Python 3.6.It redirects to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login?next=/profile/ " this link but throws an URL error.
Whereas when I manually amend the above link with this "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/profile/"  link with a "/" after login it works fine. So I assume it is an issue with the unicode "/" that doesnt get rendered when redirected.

[image: ScreenShot of the error report].

How can I make this "/" rendered after "login" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your `LOGIN_URL` setting contains the trailing slash:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
```

Alternatively, you can use the url pattern name. This has the advantage that you don't have to hardcode the login url in your settings.

```
LOGIN_URL = 'account_login'
```

If you are specifying `login_url` when you use the `login_required` decorator, you need to make sure you include the trailing slash there.

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. @login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')  worked.

Comment: There's no need to use `login_url` with the `login_required` decorator if you are using the regular login url. Just use `login_required` in your view, and set `LOGIN_URL` correctly in your settings.